# show links when mouse over text

Tags: javascript, php, css

i have a sign up option in the form.there are two types of users who can sign up 1. teacher and 2.student. when sign up option will be selected two options will come for teacher and student. i can do it by drop down list but i want it to be like those websites where options are showed when mouse pointer points the signup without click.please help me

Comment: Post your current attempt.

Comment: Dowvoted into oblivion in 3....2....1

Comment: why you guyz are always in hurry to give a down voting.. You can see this is the NEw USER. Don'te tell me you didn't make this kind of mistakes in past

Comment: @KheemaPandey I've made plenty of mistakes, and the way I learned **not** to make mistakes is by people informing me of that fact. That's what down-voting is, a tool to inform the user that their question is not a good fit for SO and needs to be improved.

Comment: but instead of giving direct down voting you can explain the terms to new User. I know many user here who have more than 5K rating and do silly mistake while posting..you must give a chance atleast to new users

Comment: @Kheema -  Also, "details" aren't a concept that is unique to programming. I will never understand why people expect us to read their minds.

Comment: @KheemaPandey The very first comment instructed the user exactly what to do. Also, the rules are clearly posted throughout the site and are accessible to anyone and everyone. Everyone makes mistakes, that is understood, but since this site is for educational purposes, mistakes need to be corrected. Not down-voting posts like this leads to others feeling it is ok to post vague, non-descript issues and therefore lowering the quality of the site as a whole.

Comment: @chris I agree with your points. After all We are humans :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Drop Down Menu Test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
div{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    }

#status{
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

div .menu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left :0px;
    width: 190px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

div:hover .menu{
display: inline-block;
}


</style>

<body>

<div id="main">
<ul>
<li id="status">Sign Up
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Teacher</li>
        <li>Student</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Are you looking to do something like this?

Comment: i am exactly looking for something like this.thank you so much